# Three.js plane rotates around a specified axis (an edge of the plane), why is it incorrect?

Tags: d3.js, three.js, 3d

All the experts out there. I have just started learning three.js and would like to ask a question.

There is a plane created from four points that is rotated around one of the edges of the face. But I never get the desired result, the plane is not in the correct position after the rotation.

For comparison, I created plane2. plane2 is the result I was expecting. Why is there a problem with plane? What am I doing wrong?

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from "../3dutils/orbit.controls.js";
import { ExtGridHelper } from "../3dutils/grid.helper";

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.initThree();
  },
  methods: {
    initThree() {

      const scene = new THREE.Scene();

      const point1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 2, 0);
      const point2 = new THREE.Vector3(2, 5, 0);
      const point3 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 2, 10);
      const point4 = new THREE.Vector3(2, 5, 10);

      const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry().setFromPoints([point1, point2, point3, point4]);
      const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x121212, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
      const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(plane);
      
      const start = new THREE.Vector3(0, 2, 0);
      const end = new THREE.Vector3(2, 5, 0);
      const direction = end.sub(start).normalize();

      
      const rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
      rotationMatrix.makeRotationAxis(direction, Math.PI * 30 / 180);
      
      plane.rotateOnAxis(direction, Math.PI * 30 / 180);

      const rotatedP3 = point3.clone().applyMatrix4(rotationMatrix);
      const rotatedP4 = point4.clone().applyMatrix4(rotationMatrix);

      const geometry2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry().setFromPoints([point1, point2, rotatedP3, rotatedP4]);
      const material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide });

      const plane2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);
      scene.add(plane2);

      // camera
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
      camera.position.set(50, 50, 50);

      // renderer
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      this.$refs.container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      // controll
      new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

      // ambient light
      const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
      scene.add(ambientLight);

      // direction light
      const directionLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
      directionLight.position.set(800, 800, 800);
      scene.add(directionLight);

      // grid helper
      const gridSize = 500;
      const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(gridSize, 100, 0x2f4f4f, 0x2f4f4f); // 
      gridHelper.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
      scene.add(gridHelper);

      const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
      scene.add(axesHelper);

      const animate = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      };

      animate();
    },
  },
};
```

If it is possible, I would like to ask you all. How is it possible to realize that plane and plane2 are in the same position. The difference in plane height can be ignored.